# How can I determine a straight of three dice in Java?

Tags: java, dice

I'm making a Java program that rolls three dice and then determines whether it's a three pair, straight, or pair.  How can I determine whether it's a straight or not?

```
static int d1, d2, d3;
static int wins, loses, ties, rounds;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char answer;

    welcome();
    while (answer != 'n') {
        DieGame.d1 = rollDie(1, 7);
        DieGame.d2 = rollDie(1, 7);
        DieGame.d3 = rollDie(1, 7);

        printDice(d1, d2, d3); 

        if (isTriple(d1, d2, d2)) {
            wins++;
        }

        else if (isStraight(d1, d2, d3)) {
            wins++;
        }


    }
}


public static boolean isStraight(int d1, int d2, int d3) {

    }
```

Here's just some of the code.  Obviously there are other methods but I'm struggling with determining a straight.  We aren't on arrays yet so I can't use that.

Comment: Hint: think of it as a collection of three values. Sort it, *then* test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
public boolean isStraight(int d1, int d2, int d3) {
   int min = getMin(d1, d2, d3);
   int mid = getMid(d1, d2, d3);
   int max = getMax(d1, d2, d3);

   if((max - mid) == 1 && (mid - min) == 1) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Where getMin, getMid, and getMax return the minimum, middle, and maximum values. Since you haven't gotten to arrays, I'll assume you can't use Math.min(), etc. So, those would look like the following.

```
public int getMin(int d1, int d2, int d3) {
  int min = d1;
  if (d2 < min) {
    min = d2;
  }
  if (d3 < min) {
    min = d3;
  }
  return min;
}
```

And so on...

Comment: Or just `return max - mid == 1 && mid - min == 1;`

Comment: You're an angel.   I knew it could be simple but I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Normally, I would do that, but seeing as to how this appears to be close to the beginning of a course, I thought I would keep the example as generic as possible

Comment: @BrandonLaidig Good point. If you put `return min;` in your method I'll upvote.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks for catching that! I can't believe I forgot that :)

Comment: @ChrisSchuck if this answer was sufficient, please select it as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean isStraight(int d1, int d2, int d3) {
    
        int min = Math.min(d1,Math.min(d2,d3))
        int max = Math.max(d1,Math.max(d2,d3))
        if((max-min)==2)
           return true;
        else
           return false;

    }
```

Comment: this can result in repeated digit returning as true. e.g. isStraight(1,2,2) =>true.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -1):

for these three results(*three pair, straight, or pair*) a very good hint can be using of *Set* collection (as it does not accept repeated values), you can put all 6 numbers into an empty set then evaluate the result by size of the set, I mean at final and after putting all the 6 values into the set:

1. if the `size` of set is `3` then the result is: `three pair`
2. if the `size` of set is `6` then the result is: `straight`
3. if the `size` of set is `5` then the result is: `pair`:

a simple sample:

```
Integer[] values = {1, 4, 6, 1, 6, 4};
Set<Integer> resultValues = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (Integer i : values) {
    resultValues.add(i);
}

switch (resultValues.size()) {
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Three Pairs");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Straight");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("One Pair");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Others");
}
```

Output:

```
Three Pairs
```

Comment: If the initial integer array is `Integer[] values = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}` you'll get a length of six, but it isn't a straight

Comment: @BrandonLaidig have you seen a **6**-sided dice which has **7** numbers? think well after that decide to downvote an answer

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, so fair enough. But the point remains that they haven't gotten to arrays yet, so it's safe to assume they haven't gotten to sets either

Comment: Also, he asked for a straight of 3. So, using a set won't help much as you could roll a 1, 4, 5 and the length would be 3, but it definitely wouldn't be a straight